# EOL while Scanning String Literal in Mycode

Tags: python, tensorflow

Well, I do understand that this error refers to the incorrect use of quotation marks, parenthesis etc, however, I can not see where in this part the error is coming from:

```
def neural_network_model(data):
    hidden_1_layer = {'weights':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([784,n_nodes_hl1])),
                     'biases':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl1]))}
    hidden_2_layer = {'weights':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl1, n_nodes_hl2]))
                     'biases':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl2]))}
    hidden_3_layer = {'weights':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl2,n_nodes_hl3])),
                     'biases':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl3]))}
    output_layer = {'weights':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl3,n_classes])),
                     'biases':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes]))}
```

Comment: Can you post the code just before this line?  An error message concerning the last symbol on a line is often due to the previous statement.  The code you posted has its quotation marks and open-close punctuation properly balanced.

Comment: @prune: 2 lines before are these:                                                                      x = tf.placeholder('float', [None,784])                                                                    y = tf.placeholder('float')

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.   The code you've given so far does not reproduce the problem.